# Copy data one excel to another excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, copy-paste

I need to copy the data of workbook 1 column C & D row data in to workbook 2 sheet3 but there is an error.

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
  Dim Openfile As String ' Openfile
  Dim lstrow As Long
  Dim i As Long
  lstrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 2 To lstrow
 'Copy the data
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").range("C:D", i).Copy
 'Activate the destination worksheet
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=range("H", i)
      Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
  'Select the target range
  range("B2:C2").Select
   'Paste in the target destination
     ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error and what is that error?.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Application Defined or object defined error (Runtime error 1004)

Comment: Is that in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").range("C:D", i).Copy`?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Yes for that line only.
It means its a workbook 1 Main sheet i need to copy the data of C & D column particular row and paste into Workbook2 sheet3 B2&C2 accordingly

Comment: Are there separate workbooks for reach copied row?  I ask because your code is opening a workbook during every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald yes exactly each row is different workbook

Comment: **Edit** `strFileName = ws.Range("H", i).Value` to `strFileName = ws.Cells(i, "H").Value`  `Range` becomes `Cells` and swap the argument order. The two argument `Range` call arguments are a beginning cell reference `A1` and an ending cell reference `B2` so `Range("A1","B2")`. Similar to a single argument call to `Range` for a multi cell range `A1:B2` as `Range("A1:B2") as opposed to a single cell range call `Range("A2")`. Also a single cell reference and multi cell reference can be used in the same two argument Range call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really try to avoid the activation and select in your code. Also, there are some things currently in it that are useless or make no sense.
Give this a try. Upon error, make sure that the strFileName is the full path to the workbook  not just the filename (refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673167/referring-to-workbook-worksheet-with-variable-names) for more info on that):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Paste()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim wb As Workbook, wbPaste As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet
  Dim strFileName As String
  Dim lstrow As Long, i As Long


  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set ws = wb.Sheets("Main")

  lstrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 2 To lstrow

    'Set data to copy
      Set CopyRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 3), ws.Cells(i, 4))
    ' Set PasteRange
      strFileName = ws.Range("H", i).Value
      'Open workbook in which you want to paste
      Set wbPaste = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
      'Define the worksheet
      Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Sheets("Sheet3")
      'Paste
      wsPaste.Range(wsPaste.Cells(2, 2), wsPaste.Cells(2, 3)).Value = CopyRange.Value
    Next i

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: change `strFileName = ws.Range("H", i).Value`